# values not getting stored in database using codeigniter

Tags: php, view, model, controller

i'm using codeigniter concept to save the records in database, i have a little bit issue with this codeing please can any one help me as im new to this concept,
the validation for form is working properly but when i try to insert and submit, the data is not getting stored in the database, im not getting wht issue im facing please 
can any one help me to solve this porblem.

Home.php(controller file)

```
    <?php  
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');  

    class Home extends CI_Controller {
        public function __construct() 
        {
            parent::__construct();

            //load database libray manually
            $this->load->database();

            //load Model
            $this->load->model('Contact_model');

            // load form and url helpers
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

            // load form_validation library
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
        }

        public function contact()  
        {  
            // Basic validation
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('subject', 'Subject', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'Message', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                $this->load->helper('url');
                $this->load->view('header');
                $this->load->view('contact'); 
                $this->load->view('footer');
            }
            else
            {
                /* load success template...
                echo "Thanks For Contacting!";*/
                //insert
                if($this->input->post('submit'))
                {
                    $name=$this->input->post('name');
                    $email=$this->input->post('email');
                    $subject=$this->input->post('subject');
                    $message=$this->input->post('message');
                    $this->Contact_model->saverecords($name,$email,$subject,$message);  
                    echo "Records Saved Successfully";
                }
            }
        }

    }  
    ?>
```

contact_model.php(Model file)

```
    <?php
        class Contact_model extends CI_Model 
        {
            //Insert
            function saverecords($name,$email,$subject,$message)
            {
                $query="insert into contact values('','$name','$email','$subject','$message')";
                $this->db->query($query);
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: have you tried checking into your error logs?

Comment: no sir how to check it

Comment: check inside your `application/logs/` directory or in your Apache/Nginx error logs.

Comment: in the query remove empty value you are passing like this  $query="insert into contact values('$name','$email','$subject','$message')";

Comment: i did not understood sir

Comment: can u please be tel me more briefly

Comment: please guide me sir

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be wrong you need to describe the columns that you're updating I suppose the format should be

`$sql = "INSERT INTO foobar(firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";`